# Freezing the parameters of a pre-trained model except specific layers

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using the pre-trained vision transformer of [ViT](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/16d62e3072955bd92b76a4ae73fefa73ecc9ee3e/torchvision/models/vision_transformer.py#L160) as my encoder. The encoder block of this model is as follows (there are some functions called inside it that you can find it in the source code and I avoid to mention for the sake of space saving):

```
class EncoderBlock(nn.Module):
"""Transformer encoder block."""

def __init__(
    self,
    num_heads: int,
    hidden_dim: int,
    mlp_dim: int,
    dropout: float,
    attention_dropout: float,
    norm_layer: Callable[..., torch.nn.Module] = partial(nn.LayerNorm, eps=1e-6),
):
    super().__init__()
    self.num_heads = num_heads

    # Attention block
    self.ln_1 = norm_layer(hidden_dim)
    self.self_attention = nn.MultiheadAttention(hidden_dim, num_heads, dropout=attention_dropout, batch_first=True)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    # MLP block
    self.ln_2 = norm_layer(hidden_dim)
    self.mlp = MLPBlock(hidden_dim, mlp_dim, dropout)

def forward(self, input: torch.Tensor):
    torch._assert(input.dim() == 3, f"Expected (batch_size, seq_length, hidden_dim) got {input.shape}")
    x = self.ln_1(input)
    x, _ = self.self_attention(x, x, x, need_weights=False)
    x = self.dropout(x)
    x = x + input

    y = self.ln_2(x)
    y = self.mlp(y)
    return x + y
```

I want to add the following module to the above-mentioned `EncoderBlock`:

```
class Adapter(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, D_features, mlp_ratio=0.25, act_layer=nn.GELU):
        super().__init__()
        #self.skip_connect = skip_connect
        D_hidden_features = int(D_features * mlp_ratio)
        self.act = act_layer()
        self.D_fc1 = nn.Linear(D_features, D_hidden_features)
        self.D_fc2 = nn.Linear(D_hidden_features, D_features)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        # x is (BT, HW+1, D)
        xs = self.D_fc1(x)
        xs = self.act(xs)
        xs = self.D_fc2(xs)
        
        x = xs
        return x
```

To be clear, I added the `Adapter` to the `EncoderBlock` as follows:

```
def __init__(
    self,
    num_heads: int,
    hidden_dim: int,
    mlp_dim: int,
    dropout: float,
    attention_dropout: float,
    norm_layer: Callable[..., torch.nn.Module] = partial(nn.LayerNorm, eps=1e-6),
):
    super().__init__()
    self.num_heads = num_heads

    # Attention block
    self.ln_1 = norm_layer(hidden_dim)
    self.self_attention = nn.MultiheadAttention(hidden_dim, num_heads, dropout=attention_dropout, batch_first=True)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    # MLP block
    self.ln_2 = norm_layer(hidden_dim)
    self.mlp = MLPBlock(hidden_dim, mlp_dim, dropout)
    
    self.adapter = Adapter(D_features = hidden_dim)

def forward(self, input: torch.Tensor):
    torch._assert(input.dim() == 3, f"Expected (batch_size, seq_length, hidden_dim) got {input.shape}")
    x = self.ln_1(input)
    x, _ = self.self_attention(query=x, key=x, value=x, need_weights=False)
    
    x = self.adapter(x)      # I added
 
    x = self.dropout(x)

    x = x + input

    y = self.ln_2(x)
    y = self.mlp(y)
    return x + y
```

I'm using the pre-trained model of ViT and I need to freeze whole parameters of ViT model except the `Adapter` modules that are added to the layers of ViT.
Although I know how to freeze the whole ViT, by considering the fact that the whole ViT model is built based on stacking the `EncoderBlock` layers, how I can unfreeze the added 'Adapter' layers?

Answer (score 0):

In order to freeze the whole encoder except the `Adapter` module the following strategy can be used:

```
for name, param in model.encoder.parameters()():
    if 'Adapter' not in name:
        param.requires_grad = False
```